# How to get tokens from a contracts 0x0 address?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, contract-invocation, addresses

I was having a deep dive through an address I found interesting and noticed that all his tokens always came from a contracts 0x0 address. How is this done?

I assume this is how smart contracts work and the address owner can somehow write a smart contract to buy the tokens from that address but I am not sure how I would go about doing something similar. Am I able to write a contract like this within EtherScan's write contract feature?

Answer (score 0):

> I was having a deep dive through an address I found interesting and noticed that all his tokens always came from a contracts 0x0 address. How is this done?

There is no standard for this. However minting and burn events generally use the address 0x0 as the source and destination to identify new tokens were created or the token supply was reduced.

This is because the original ERC-20 standard had only `Transfer` event, not `Mint` and not `Burn`